# How to shift a LinearLayout when a SlidingDrawer expands?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, slidingdrawer

I am trying to implement a panel in a fragment that can expand on button click from the right side of the screen. I can't use the navigation drawer, because I already have navigation drawers from both left and right sides.

The idea is to achieve something like that:

[image]

I was almost able to do it with the `SlidingDrawer` widget (it's deprecated..), the only problem is that I don't know how to make the LinearLayout to appear in the middle and then to shift when the button to expand the `SlidingDrawer` is clicked.

I have the following code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button handle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.handle);
        SlidingDrawer drawer = (SlidingDrawer) findViewById(R.id.slidingDrawer);

        drawer.setOnDrawerOpenListener(new SlidingDrawer.OnDrawerOpenListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened() {
            }
        });

        drawer.setOnDrawerCloseListener(new SlidingDrawer.OnDrawerCloseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed() {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And the `XML` code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.test.slidingdrawertest.slidingdrawertest.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TEST TEST TEST" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <SlidingDrawer
            android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:content="@+id/content"
            android:handle="@+id/handle"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/handle"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Expand" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TEST TEST TEST" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </SlidingDrawer>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Your LinearLayout has to go to the left then get smaller when the other one is getting closer than him ? Like compressed between your expanded panel and the left limit

Comment: @Tritri Yes, that's right. I am trying to change the gravity of the `LinearLayout` but with no success. At the moment I get a `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams` exception when I try to get the `LinearLayout` and change the parameters..

Comment: I think this error is because your LinearLayout depends of the RelativeLayout so: `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);` And the gravity that you set is for the textView and not the linearLayout itself but layout_gravity would work if you would be in LinearLayout. But even with that I don't if it could work. I would do something more with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it, it actually wasn't so difficult, but it's a little tricky. Here is the solution:

The xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/topLayout"
    tools:context="com.test.slidingdrawertest.slidingdrawertest.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TEST" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <SlidingDrawer
            android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:content="@+id/content"
            android:handle="@+id/handle"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/handle"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Expand" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TEST TEST TESTT" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </SlidingDrawer>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The code in `MainActivity.java`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button handle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.handle);
        SlidingDrawer drawer = (SlidingDrawer) findViewById(R.id.slidingDrawer);
        final View k = findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

        drawer.setOnDrawerOpenListener(new SlidingDrawer.OnDrawerOpenListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened() {
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
                k.setLayoutParams(params);
            }
        });

        drawer.setOnDrawerCloseListener(new SlidingDrawer.OnDrawerCloseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed() {
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
                k.setLayoutParams(params);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And the explanation: I had to give main main layout an id (in XML) and then find it in the code behind, then I had to apply new parameters to it when the drawer opens or closes. Basically, we need to find the parent layout and set the parameters to it.

Now the `LinearLayout` is able to shift it's position on drawer open, and it goes back to it's original position on drawer close. Next step is to make this process with an animation, so it's smooth and doesn't just jump back and forth to the new positions.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your XML like this

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    tools:context="com.test.slidingdrawertest.slidingdrawertest.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/left"                // this is your linear layout 
      android:layout_width="match_parent"   // that you want to shift left
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/right"  // apply this property due to 
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"  //which if the width of sliding menu 
      android:gravity="center"             //increase it will automatically compressed
      android:background="#aa00aa"


        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TEST TEST TEST" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/right"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="#0000aa"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <SlidingDrawer
            android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer"
            android:layout_width="200dp"          // you can check by increasing or decreasing the with of this slidingdrawer
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:content="@+id/content"
            android:handle="@+id/handle"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/handle"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Expand" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TEST TEST TEST" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </SlidingDrawer>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

apart from this if set any layout to the right of your linear layout which is initially `GONE` and as you click on the button its visibility changed to `INVISIBLE/VISIBLE` so it will shift the linear layout to left. Hope that helps!

Comment: I am not sure I understand what to set to the right of which linear layout. Can you please clarify ?

Comment: Kindly check the edited code with comments and let me know if any doubt.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I've tried that but it doesn't shift the left linear layout. It stays static even when expanding the sliding drawer, because the widths are fixed when the app is started.

Comment: Have you tried making the width of sliding drawer to wrap content?

Comment: Yes, I tried that but then it takes the whole screen. Btw I am testing on a tablet in landscape mode, but this shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a little exemple here is my solution: (I don't know if Avani Nagar's solution works or not):

```
TextView res;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final TextView img = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.second);
    res = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.first);

    img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            img.setX(img.getX() - 5);
            changew(img.getX());
        }
    });
}

private void changew(float w){
    res.getLayoutParams().width = (int)(res.getX() +w);
    res.requestLayout();
    res.invalidate();
}
```

The xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/black">

<TextView
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/first"
    android:text="bonjourrrrrr"
    android:id="@+id/second"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />

<TextView
    android:text="salutttttttt"
    android:id="@id/first"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light" />


</RelativeLayout>
```